# App freezes when starting starting a while loop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Ass the title states. When i press button to change from the menu to the game and lets the loop run. the game freezes and doesn't change the screen. I can se that the button is still pressed down even after i let it go.

```
package com.example.jumpking.ui.theme

class Gameloop(
    private val game: Game) {

    var jumpPower = 1f
    var jumpY = 0f
    var sinceLastFrame = 0L
    fun loop() {
        while(Application.gamestatus == Application.GAMESTATUS.RUNNING) {
            if (game.jumpButton) {
                game.player.move(0f, jumpPower)
            }
            if (game.leftButton && ! game.rightButton) {
                game.player.move(-jumpPower, 0f)
            }
            if (!game.leftButton && game.rightButton) {
                game.player.move(jumpPower, 0f)

            }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JumpKingTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val gameclass = Game()
                    val gameloop = Gameloop(gameclass)
                    when (Application.currentState) {
                        Application.GAMESTATE.SCOREBOARD -> ScoreboardScreen()
                        Application.GAMESTATE.PLAYING -> {gameclass.GameScreen(gameloop)}
                        Application.GAMESTATE.MENU -> MenuScreen()
                    }
                    gameloop.loop()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your loop is running on the UI thread, meaning that your loop "freezes" the UI until its done. You should run the loop in coroutine or thread to keep it away from UI thread.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        JumpKingTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                //Use remember, otherwise your game and loop will be new instances on recompose
                val gameclass = remember { Game() }
                val gameloop = remember { Gameloop(gameclass) }
                
                //Start loop in launched effect, so it will be called once
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
                    withContext(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
                        //Start the loop on single thread dispatcher
                        gameloop.loop()
                    }
                })
                
                when (Application.currentState) {
                    Application.GAMESTATE.SCOREBOARD -> ScoreboardScreen()
                    Application.GAMESTATE.PLAYING -> {gameclass.GameScreen(gameloop)}
                    Application.GAMESTATE.MENU -> MenuScreen()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to use a single-threaded dispatcher instead of IO, though because different properties of the GameLoop class will be getting modified, and the GameLoop class isn’t thread-safe. If the properties that are modified are used by Compose, it should use Dispatchers.Main, and the game loop function should be a suspend function that has a `yield()` call inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah, single-threaded dispatcher makes much more sence, i will update my answer. Properties used by compose doens't need to be updated from `Dispatchers.Main`, it has to be wrapped in `MutableState<T>` to tell the composer to recompose the screen.